# Desktop-native graphical db management tool for RethinkDB?

Tags: windows, database, desktop-client, database-browser

MySQL & SQL server have some awesome desktop-native tools which enable rapid ad-hoc querying & updating the database, with massive performance gains (specifically, eg. Navicat, and SQL Server).

RethinkDB has a built-in "Data Explorer"; however, this is really suboptimal for poking data with the mouse -specifically, all query requires writing a full JS statement by hand.

Outside of the web administration tool's "Data explorer", is there any high-leverage desktop GUI tool available for poking RethinkDB's data?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [RethinkDB GUI Client](http://utils.codehangar.io/rethink) for Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux

ReQLPro is free Desktop GUI that was built to help fill that void for RethinkDB.  Right now it mostly covers the "poking data with the mouse" need your looking for. It is still under active development and looking for feedback to help prioritize the roadmap.

It is an electron-built app, and runs on Mac OS X, Windows (Tested on Windows 10), and Linux (Tested on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit)

The basic features available right now are:

- Add/Edit/Remove Connections/Favorites
- Add/Remove Databases
- Add/Remove Tables
- View table data in a table view with sorting and pagination
- Quick links to delete or edit a document via row in the table view
- JSON Text Editor for Creating/Editing Documents

Here is a screenshot that highlights the look and feel of the app:
[image: ReQLPro RethinkDB]

*Disclaimer: I help build and manage this app.*

Comment: The link you posted may be invalid in the future.  Can you explain why your answer is appropriate?

Comment: Cass, you have potential for a great answer here, but could you please add at least a screenshot and explain how data can be edited? Thanks!

Comment: Seems the tool is out of date now, now more updates in its github repo for years.

Comment: link is dead...

Answer (score 0):

**A** The third party admin tools that are listed by RethingDb all seem to be outdated:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/third-party-admin-tools/

Same for

https://github.com/GaryChangCN/NiRethink

The closest one seems to be **chateau** (last change 5 years ago). However, it does not seem to provide much more than the rethink web ui:

https://github.com/neumino/chateau

```
npm install chateou
chateou -f config.js
```

---

Example config.js:

```
// RethinkDB settings
exports.host = 'localhost';    // RethinkDB host
exports.port = 28015;          // RethinkDB driver port
exports.authKey = '';          // Authentification key (leave an empty string if you did not set one)

// Express settings
exports.expressPort = 3000;    // Port used by express
exports.debug = true;          // Debug mode
exports.network = '127.0.0.1'  // Network the node app will run on
```

---

Open chateau in browser with

http://localhost:3000

[image]

---

**B.** I checked following tools but they all **don't support RethinkDb**:

- **Navicat**

**mongodb**.

https://www.navicat.com/en/products

- **Dbeaver**

**mongodb** and **couchdb**:

https://dbeaver.com/databases/

- **Tableplus**

CockroachDB, Snowflake, Cassandra, Redis, Vertica, MongoDb

https://docs.tableplus.com/#supported-databases

- **Aqua Data Studio**

See

https://www.aquaclusters.com/app/home/project/public/aquadatastudio/wikibook/Documentation22.0/page/3/Supported-RDBMS-Servers

---

**C.** Details about the web ui that comes with RethinkDb:

https://rethinkdb.com/docs/administration-tools/

Open with:

http://localhost:8080

Or adapt port with docker command, for example use port 8070 instead of 8080 for web ui:

```
docker run -it -p 8070:8080 -p 28015:28015 -p 29015:29015 --name rethinkdb rethinkdb
```

Screenshot of web gui, showing its Data Explorer:

[image]